# Iterating through ListCollectionView using foreach

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Since ListCollectionView doesn't support indexer (ex View[0]), the only way I found to iterate through filtered/sorted list is to use foreach.

1) Will foreach make sure that order of items in view is preserved during iteration? if not, what is the alternative?

2) Is there a strongly typed ListCollectionView? I am missing a lot linq extension methods, and having lots of FindMaxThis, FindFirstThat... :)

Comment: just logically it seems iteration preserves the order, else one might get different results, just because it's the nth time iterating. Iteration cannot be a random results generator.

Comment: Well, I remember once I read about it, and the answer was: depends on the collection it is iterating... If you look at SO, you will see that there where similar questions about this. Anyway, List<T> will preserve order for sure, and I am using List<T> all the time, so I am safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When you use foreach with ListCollectionView you will probably get an Enumerator from the underlying collection (**InternalList** property). If you initialize it with an instance of List<> then you can be pretty sure that the enumeration will be in order.

2) There are two options to do it. First you can use the internal list and either cast it to a strongly typed collection or store the reference to it somewhere in your class. Second is to use **Cast<>** directly on the ListCollectionView instance. For performance critical apps I would choose the first approach.

```
var collection = new ListCollectionView(new List<int>());
var even = collection
    .Cast<int>()
    .Where(n => n%2 == 0);
```

Comment: Hi, as for the number 2), I cannot use SourceCollection property (internal list), since it contains all items, not the filtered/sorted. This would create different results from the expected ones. And since Cast<> call would create each time new enumerable collection, that would create bad performance. I am not sure why there isnt any strongly typed editable collection view in wppf.